# How to copy some part of html as styled text from a web page with .Net or javascript

Tags: javascript, html, .net, copy, copy-paste

I've created a web site for my customer, and I've to copy nearly 1000 of web page content as styled text and insert them to my web site.

I've an admin page to do this manually but for first time it takes to much to insert 1000 product information by hands.

It could be very usefull to just giving urls and gettin html contents as styled text to insert. It should be done with javascript and .Net. Do you have any suggestion on this?

Comment: You mention .NET, so do you want this done server or client side?

Comment: It doesn't matter where this done, both client and server side is usefull. But in the end, I'll save result to database with .Net on server side.

Comment: Not sure what the situation is then. What does the input look like? I mean, is it a static HTML file, or generated HTML or something else? And it needs to be put in the database, also in HTML format?

Comment: The input is a response of an external web page request as html text, actually a known part of it (I mean a div with specific id attribute on the response html). And the output is a styled html text. When I get the text I'll save it to database.